# Android: drawableLeft setting alpha

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there anyway to set alpha on a drawable sitting within an editText as a drawableLeft?

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_middle_bg"
                android:id="@+id/birthday_overlay"
                android:editable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="Birthday"
                android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cake_black_24dp"/>
```

[image: birthdayIcon]

I got the icon from the material icon library by Google. The icon is where alpha is 1 (so full black). I want to make it slightly grey by making alpha 0.5 for example.

I guess I can use GIMP / Photoshop to change the alpha but would prefer to use android to do this programmatically.

Comment: you can't give it in xml but use setAlpha() programmatically.

Comment: did my answer work for you below @Simon ?

Comment: Hi, I will need to modify the code a little before I can test it. Currently im getting a drawable: Drawable[] birthdayDrawables = birthday.getCompoundDrawables(); and I cannot pass it into your method as you have a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is eventually what I did to achieve my desired outcome.

```
    Drawable[] birthdayDrawable = birthdayOverlay.getCompoundDrawables();
    birthdayDrawable[0].setAlpha(128); //set it at 128 so that it has 50% opacity. The opactiy here ranges from 0 to 255.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public static void setAlpha(View view, float alpha){ 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) { 
        final AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
        animation.setDuration(0);
        animation.setFillAfter(true); 
        view.startAnimation(animation); 
    } 
    else 
        view.setAlpha(alpha); 
}
```

Use this method. Pass the argument as your drawableLeft from the EditText. This works for <= API 16 and > API 16.

Answer (score 1):

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable);

// set opacity
drawable.setAlpha(10);

//Set it
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: My answer accounts for the deprecated setAlpha method. This way is deprecated <= API 16.

Answer (score 0):

I search many and found this unique - for my research - solution:

I make with a CountDownTimer, work good.

```
Drawable[] compundDrawables = textview_with_drawableLef_Image.getCompoundDrawables();
Drawable leftCompoundDrawable = compundDrawables[0];
```

And after in a countdowntimer, I blink the `leftCompoundDrawable` setting the:

```
leftCompoundDrawable.setApha(AlphaNumber);
```

Work Good, Need a little adjust of countDownInterval and Alpha Value Step, check when alpha is minor to 0 or more to 255 (Alpha in Drawables is from 0 to 255) and change step alpha to + or --, but is easy to adjust for good look.

The CountDownTimer is very usseful in some cases.